# Plotting graph using realtime data - Socket.io

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, socket.io, c3.js

I'm using `setInterval` function to refresh bar chart with new values -> [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fLGrY4LWgQJXMe0f4Qij?p=preview)

```
$interval(function() {
    $http({
      url: 'chartData.json', 
      method: "GET",
    }).then(function(json) {
        $scope.names = formatData(json.data)
        $scope.chart.load({json: $scope.names, keys: { value: ['Bryan', 'John', 'Alicia', 'Jenny'] }});
    });
  }, 1000);
```

and now I'm trying to refresh graph with realtime data from Socket.io ->

```
socketio.on('chartData', function (json) {
    $scope.names = formatData(json.data)
    $scope.chart.load({json: $scope.names, keys: { value: ['Bryan', 'John', 'Alicia', 'Jenny'] }});
  });
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yI5iDDrwRF2SBSGBMXYT?p=preview)

On the backend side, there is a NodeJS which constantly emit new data

```
 socket.on("chartData", function(message) {
  io.emit("message",  message);
 });
```

, but chart doesn't displayed. Is there some other libraries for achieving similar functionality?